# Access Redmine through PHP

Tags: php, authentication, redmine, activeresource

I am trying to access Redmine through PHP with the ActiveResource class. But when I try and login I just get redirected to the github of activeresource.

My PHP is running on a localhost but the redmine I want to access is on another, already online.

Am I not able to access it because its not running on the same server? The tutorial on Redmine.org seems simple, what am I overlooking?

Redmine RESTful API access is of course enabled

```
<?php

require_once ('ActiveResource.php');

class Issue extends ActiveResource {
    var $site = 'username:password@helpdesk.example.com:3000';
    var $request_format = 'xml'; // REQUIRED!
}

// find issues
$issues = $issue->find ('all');
for ($i=0; $i < count($issues); $i++) {
    echo $issues[$i]->subject;
}

?>
```

EDIT: I've also tried PHP-Redmine-API, but didn't work out either. In the mean time, all attempts connecting through JSON, JAVA and C# were successful.

php noob here.